# How do i add watermark a text on full image?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using itextsharp in my web application.I have to add a watermark which repeats on whole image from top to bottom.How to add watermark on whole image and is it good to use itextsharp for watermarking.

Answer (score 1):

See this:

http://codeglobe.blogspot.com.es/2009/01/watermarking-image-in-cnet.html